# Excel getting date ranges based on month and year

Tags: excel, date

Hi i have year and month given but im trying to obtain this result
[enter image description here][1]

Only based on the given information which is the year and the month

Is this possible?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6WZz.jpg

Comment: Given month is `July` but date started from `Jun`, how?

Comment: So you don't know the day?

Comment: Yes i did this manually.by checking on calendar to get the dates for that month.

Comment: There's june dates included because it falls on that week range for the month of july

Comment: Welcome to SO. Looks like you are trying to get the natural weeks (Sunday to Saturday, American system) given a month and a year. So if you say July 2022, weeks would be 26th June (Sunday) to 2nd July (Saturday),  and so on. Probably you can make several IFS to get this but because months can have different number of natural weeks, probably an VBA solution would be best solution to avoid blank cells filled with formulas.